# CSS: Position Dynamically Sized div to Bottom of Static Div

Tags: html, css, chat

I'm adding chat functionality to my WebSocket based web app. In conventional chat windows, the eldest message is at the top of the window and the newest at the bottom. [image: Conventional chat]

My implementation should share this typical, top to bottom element order. However, in conventional chat windows, the eldest message sticks to the top of the frame. My implementation should have the youngest message sticking to the bottom of the frame. From what I've seen of my son playing it, Minecraft has this ideal chat interface. In truth, the Minecraft chat interface appears to resemble exactly what I want to implement.[image: Ideal chat]

How, in CSS, can I make chat messages stick to the bottom of their window?

This would be easy if `calc()` offered a means to refer to the current height of the element it is being applied to, as I could do something like

```
position: relative;
top: calc(240px - [current element height]);
```

where 240px is the static height of the chat window.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any code of your existing chat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, put `position:relative` on a parent container

```
#container{
position:relative;
}
```

then, put `position:absolute` on the chat window

```
#chat{
position:absolute;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

This should handle dynamic heights.

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I'll accept your answer when this StackOverflow imposed timer is up.

Comment: If you'd care to explain, why does the parent need relative positioning?

Comment: @Scruffy If the parent does not have relative postioning and you use position absolute on the child element, it willl position relative to the window. However, when you specify a parent with position:relative, it will position relative to the parent.

Comment: @AmmarCSE * It will be positioned relative to the closest ancestor that has a `position` other than `static`. If there isn't one it will be positioned relative to the window :)

Comment: @Scruffy, take a look at Goerges comment for a more correct/detailed answer

Comment: @AmmarCSE Duly noted. Thanks to AmmarCSE and George. This is in production now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

html

```
<div id="staticDiv"></div>
```

css

```
#staticDiv{
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background:yellow;
    position:relative; //static div position relative
}

#addedDiv{
    position: absolute; //dynamically added div position absolute
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    background:red;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;    
}
```

javascript

```
var a = "<div id='addedDiv'></div>";
document.getElementById('staticDiv').innerHTML = a;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qhgewc8n/1/

Comment: I'm seeking to do this in pure CSS, ideally without JavaScript's involvement, and I certainly wouldn't expect to have to use jQuery for something like this.

Comment: I have updated the answer using javascript. What do you mean by "pure css"?

Comment: By 'pure CSS' I refer to CSS and CSS alone; not using JavaScript or anything similar.

Comment: @Scruffy I got it , ignore the javascript part. :)

Comment: I'm going to assume that you wanted to show `addedDiv` as a child of `staticDiv`. You could have just included that in the HTML. Anyway, better construction of `addedDiv` might go like `a = document.createElement("div"); a.id = "addedDiv"; document.getElementById("staticDiv").appendChild(a);`.